# Is is possible to check out the publish comments on Facebook for a particular URI?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Facebook has a very interesting API that can get public stats for a URI with its share_count, comment_count and like_count. I noticed that this URI:

`http://baike.baidu.com/view/409608.htm`

has 31 shares, 10 likes and 7 comments.

Is it possible to see the content of comments for this URI?

Comment: Where are the comments on the page? I can't see any...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no comments on that page.

You can check this using `https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=og_object{comments}&id=http://baike.baidu.com/view/409608.html`

Source:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I got: `{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#4) Application request limit reached",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 4
   }
}`